# MySQL Script to SET new Column Values Based on Another Columns value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an existing database with an existing table and in that table I have a column called "packageno" which stands for Package Number. I have over 400 rows of database content. Each Unique row has a Package Number. But Now, I added a column called "packagedescription" which stands for the Package Description. Right now the new column is empty. But I have a legend for the package description in PHP code, for example:

```
if ($packageno == 1) {
 $description = 'Interior Rooms';
 }
if (packageno == 2) { 
 $description = 'Exterior Rooms';
 }
```

Etc....

But from the beginning, I didn't add the description. Instead, I added the package number.

So, what I would like to do is UPDATE or SET those empty database fields in the packagedescription column, with the actual description of the package. How would I write a MySQL script to enter the description of all existing rows, using the packageno?

I know a little MySQL but I have never done anything like this to existing rows.

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` query will be

```
UPDATE table_name SET packagedescription = 'Interior Rooms' 
WHERE packageno = 1

UPDATE table_name SET packagedescription = 'Exterior Rooms' 
WHERE packageno = 2
```

Same for others as well....

Comment: Cool! So Simple! So I have 16 packages so i would run that script with the different descriptions and package numbers 16 different times. Thank you! Very simple! Sometimes we think too hard!

Comment: @PhilMulkins Yes you have to run this query for all 16 packages with the different descriptions and package numbers. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it in one query:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET packagedescription = 
    IF(packageno = 1, 'Interior Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 2, 'Exterior Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 3, 'Some Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 4, 'Other Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 5, 'Outdoor Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 6, 'Indoor Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 7, 'Commercial Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 8, 'Residential Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 9, 'Industrial Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 10, 'Kitchen Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 11, 'Office Rooms',
    IF(packageno = 12, 'Bedrooms', NULL))))))))))))
```

You could also create a PackageNumberDescription table and do the update from that like this:

```
PackageNo  PackageDescription
---------  ------------------
1          Interior Rooms
2          Exterior Rooms

UPDATE packages p JOIN PackageNumberDescription d on p.packageno = d.packageno SET p.packagedescription = d.packagedescription
```

Comment: Thank you.. i were looking for the exact thing :)... this helped me a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you have a small number of ids, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE package SET description = 'Interior Rooms' WHERE packageNo = 1;
UPDATE package SET description = 'Exterior Rooms' WHERE packageNo = 2;
```

Might get a bit annoying if you have hundreds or thousands.

Or, instead of duplicating descriptions, you could have a seperate table, that has the descriptions and link to it.

```
PackageID    Description
---------    --------------
1            Interior Rooms
2            Exterior Rooms
```

Then you could change your selects to include the other table:

```
SELECT * FROM package p INNER JOIN packageRooms pr ON p.packageID = pr.packageID
```